# Proof that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

This is my attempt. My instructor said it was incorrect. I would like to know exactly where my mistake is.

Suppose $x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

So, $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0 \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb R \ s.t. \ if \ |x - y| < \delta \ \text{then} \ |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

In this case, $|x - y| < \delta \ \text{and} \ |x^2 - y^2| < \epsilon$

$|(x - y)(x + y)| < \epsilon$

$|(x - y)| |(x + y)| < \epsilon$

$\delta|x + y| < \epsilon$

Notice, $|x + y|$ is unbounded on the real line. So $x$ and $y$ can be made arbitrarily large. So there will not always be a $\delta$ that will make all values of $x$ and $y$ less than an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.

Therefore, $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition as to why it's not uniformly continuous is correct, but your proof doesn't make any sense. Start with the definition of *not* uniformly continuous, which is what you're trying to prove.

There exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $x,y$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, but $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \epsilon_0$.

In this case, just choose $\epsilon_0=1$. Then for every $\delta$, try to come up with $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$, but $|x-y||x+y|\geq 1$. Let $x$ be arbitrary and pick $y=x+\delta/2$. Then $|x-y|=\delta/2<\delta$ is satisfied and
$$
|x-y||x+y|=\frac{\delta}{2}\left(2x+\frac{\delta}{2}\right).
$$
If $x$ is sufficiently large....

Comment: Honestly, I like all of the answers I got, but I think this one was the most complete. Really though, all of these answers were great. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

The intuition is not bad, but it is incorrect. From $|(x-y)(x+y)|<\varepsilon$ you cannot go to $\delta|x+y|\le\varepsilon$. Indeed, by applying $|x-y|<\delta$, you have $|(x-y)(x+y)|<\delta|x+y|$. So you have that one expression (say $|(x-y)(x+y)|$) is bounded by two different estimates ($\delta|x+y|$ and $\varepsilon$) but you cannot conclude anything about wich one is bigger.

A correct approach is trying to find a concrete value of $\varepsilon$ for wich for any $\delta, you have the oppose inequality.

For example, take $\varepsilon=1$ and try to prove that for any $\delta>0$ you always can find $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ and $|x^2-y^2|\ge 1$. And to do that, your intuition about the factor $(x+y)$ will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single mistake. Even if every step were correct, which is not the case, this doesn’t have the right logical structure to be a proof that the function $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous. For that you need to show that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that no matter what $\delta>0$ you choose, there are points $x_\delta,y_\delta\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x_\delta-y_\delta|<\delta$, but $|x_\delta^2-y_\delta^2|\ge\epsilon$. For example, you could let $\epsilon=1$ and for each $\delta>0$ show how to find points $x_\delta$ and $y_\delta$ such that $|x_\delta-y_\delta|<\delta$, but $|x_\delta^2-y_\delta^2|\ge 1$.

I mentioned that not every step is correct: in particular, $|x-y|\cdot|x+y|<\epsilon$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ do **not** imply that $\delta|x+y|<\epsilon$.

That said, I suspect that you do have a reasonable intuitive understanding of why $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with sequences

Let
$$x_n=n \;\; and\;y_n=n+\frac 2n$$

we have
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|x_n-y_n|=0$$

But

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|x_n^2-y_n^2|=4\ne0$$

thus
$x\mapsto x^2 $ is not uniformly continuous at $\Bbb R$.

We proved that with $\epsilon=3 $ and any $ \eta>0 $, we take $ n $ such that $ \frac 1n<\eta $ and check that
$$|x_n-y_n|=\frac 1n <\eta$$
but
$$|x_n^2-y_n^2|=4+\frac{4}{n^2}>3$$